# NoSleep.js trigger by auto click does not work

Tags: jquery, click

I know it (must be wrapped in a user input event handler e.g. a mouse or touch handler) in order to make the playvideo works.

```
var noSleep = new NoSleep();

function enableNoSleep() {
  noSleep.enable();
  document.removeEventListener('click', enableNoSleep, false);
}

// Enable wake lock.
// (must be wrapped in a user input event handler e.g. a mouse or touch handler)
document.addEventListener('click', enableNoSleep, false);

// ...

// Disable wake lock at some point in the future.
// (does not need to be wrapped in any user input event handler)
noSleep.disable();
```

It works when I use finger manually click the button , but when I use jquery to auto trigger the button then the play video does not work.

And i also find out that, after i use finger click it then I implement timer to click it repeatedly with 5 sec. it works also.

But what I want is the button was hidden in display and then trigger the nosleep at background.

I test in Iphone X.

Anyone know any solution to achieve that?